# Google Maps loading multiple markers from asynctask

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, android-asynctask

Hi I am currently working Google maps in android. Wher I retrieved the list of latitude,longitude and snippet values from mysql database and trying to show it in Google maps.This the code I tried now,but I did't get marker in map,

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,Double>> vehiclehistory1= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Double>>();
double latitude;
double longitude;
for(int i=0;i<user.length();i++)
{
    System.out.println("forloop i valuie"+i);
    JSONObject c1 = user.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject c2 = c1.getJSONObject(TAG_SRES);

    vehicle_reg_numb = c2.getString(TAG_Vechicle_REG);
    latitude= c2.getDouble(TAG_Latitude);
    longitude = c2.getDouble(TAG_Longitude);
    speed = c2.getString(TAG_Speed);
    exceed_speed_limit=c2.getString(TAG_Exceed_Speed);
    bus_tracking_timestamp = c2.getString(TAG_bus_tracking_timestamp);
    address=c2.getString(TAG_address);
    map1.put(TAG_Latitude,latitude);
    map1.put(TAG_Longitude,longitude);
    map.put(TAG_Speed, speed);
    map.put(TAG_address, address);

    vehiclehistory1.add(map1);
    vehiclehistory.add(map);

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    super.onPostExecute(file_url);
    cDialog.dismiss();
    for (int i = 0; i < vehiclehistory1.size(); i++) {
        LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(vehiclehistory1.get(i).latitude), Float.parseFloat(vehiclehistory1.get(i).longitude));
        Marker storeMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(pinLocation)
            .title(vehiclehistory1.get(i).pinname)
            .snippet(vehiclehistory1.get(i).address)
        );
    }
}
```

I am getting latitude is unresolved type.Can anyone tell me where I did mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
  LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory1.get(i).latitude), Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory1.get(i).longitude));
```

instead of Parse Float used `Double` for `Latitude` and `Longitude`

Comment: @M.D thank you..I tried with that too.I am getting latitude and longitude both should get cannot be resolved or it is not field

Comment: @micky Are you store latitude and longitude as String?

Comment: @micky then there is no need to parse it in Double.

Comment: @micky try this `LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(vehiclehistory1.get(i).latitude, vehiclehistory1.get(i).longitude);`

Comment: @D.K I tried but again same prblm...Sry for asking more help

Comment: I am getting the error in new LatLng(vehiclehistory1.get(i).get(latitude), vehiclehistory1.get(i).get(longitude));,where the place of.latitude and .longitude )

Comment: @micky ok first tell what is vehiclehistory1 and post it?

Comment: #M.K it is an Arraylist of Hash MAp..I pasted the declaration of vehicle arraylist in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57410/discussion-between-m-d-and-micky).